# How to efficiently implement NotInList behaviour for Combobox in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, events, combobox

All we know the famous NotInList event of combo box in world of VB6 , VB.net and MS-Access.

Its surprising how Delphi Rad Studio does not provide this IMPORTANT frequently requested feature in their combo box and similar controls?

How to efficiently implement this in Delphi ( using Data aware combo box linked to FireDac dataset)?

We in our Application use a primitive solution as in the following:

1. In OnExit combo box event , we search for the .Text in associated Dataset.
2. if we don't find it, we show message to the user: (Item Not found in List, add it now?)
3. if user choose OK then we add the new item and refresh the dataset and update combo box items.

Is their more efficient way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: What you describe seems to be pretty much what is [happening with Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.ComboBox.NotInList). Except you can't type in a combobox that's limited to list in Delphi. I would do the same you do. Of course you risk creating many duplicates of similar/ same items misspelled, with spaces etc. Maybe not desired ?

Comment: The Bonus KSVC / Raize components included with latter Delphi releases has such a combo box. Install using the GetIt package manager.

Comment: You can evaluate not using Data-ware components. When an element does not exist in the list, insert it into Dataset (1) and insert intoi the List (2). In this way, avoid performing the Refresh after each insertion.
At the beginning you will have to fill the list by traversing the Dataset only once.